# How to do versioning in Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

In RESTful world, we typically follow versioning by either embedding the version in the route or in accept headers. What's the best practice when it comes to Cloud functions, in order to support multiple versions of the same function.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be any different than any existing conventions you would like to follow.  You can define your own express app and handle URLs with placeholders for different path components, if you wish.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, would you mind posting that comment as an answer? I believe it's what suits OP's situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own Express app and handle URLs with placeholders for different path components, if you wish to follow any existing versioning convention. This is not impossible in Cloud Functions.